# Itunes connect and keywords

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to know do I need to separate keywords with commas and what is the best way to make keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a nice writeup of how to do keywords in their ["iTunes Connect Developer Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/FirstSteps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH19-SW2) (and I've linked to the "First Steps" section which talks about keywords).

And yes, you should separate your keywords with commas.

There are a number of tutorials and helpful hints guides for choosing the right keywords that can be found online, [like this one](http://www.bluecloudsolutions.com/blog/app-store-keywords-choose-terms).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should separate your keywords with commas. I am using sensor tower for keywords research and it's quite good. You can read more about it [here](https://blog.sensortower.com/blog/2013/01/31/how-to-improve-your-keywords-using-app-store-rankings/).